# Jest mock function does not register call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, axios

I have a react component with a method requesting my api.
For testing purposes I mocked the module [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).
[Jest](https://jestjs.io/en) does recognize the first call with get, but not the
second with post, except it is stated before the get statement. I can
log that the axios.post.mock.result has a Promise for value in my react component.
In my test it is empty.
I isolated the problem like this:

My component method

```js
import axios from 'axios';

async getData(data) {
 let response = await axios.get('/api',
  {
   params: {
    data
   }
  });
 if (response.status === 200) {
  response = await axios.post('/api',
   response.data
  );
  if (response.status === 200) {
   this.setState({ data: true });
  }
 }
}

render() {
  if (!this.state.data) {
    return (
    <button 
    onClick={() => this.getData(this.state.input)}
    >Click me</button>)
  } else {
    return (<p>Success</p>);
}
```

The test

```js
import {render, fireEvent} from 'react-testing-library';
import axios from 'axios';
import App from '../App';

jest.mock('axios');

axios.get.mockResolvedValue({ status: 200, data: { hello: 'world' } });
axios.post.mockResolvedValue({ status: 200 });

test('Component uses axios', () => {
 let app = render(<App />);
 fireEvent.click(app.getByText('Click me'));
 expect(axios.get).toBeCalled();
 expect(axios.post).toBeCalled();
});
```

Comment: axios.post is called asynchronously. You have no promise to chain to wait for it. react-testing-library isn't suited for implementation testing any way. If you want to do this, use Enzyme. In react-testing-library you just simulate a click and assert its effect on DOM.

Comment: Do you mean then/catch with chaining. I use instead await for later checking the value of  the status. Please explain the error here. I checked if the the expect comes before the post call but it isn't (asynchronous). Also documentation says react-testing-library tries to replace enzyme.

Comment: I don't think the documentation says anything like that. They are orthogonal.  react-testing-library does blackbox functional testing.

Comment: https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro under This solution "This library is a replacement for Enzyme.", maybe I misunderstood context. Enzyme can go deeper than DOM but this isn't necessary.

Comment: The author is opinionated regarding testing approaches. Notice that it emphasizes the difference between them, *While you can follow these guidelines using Enzyme itself, enforcing this is harder because of all the extra utilities that Enzyme provides (utilities which facilitate testing implementation details)*. I'll post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react-testing-library is primarily intended for blackbox functional testing and isn't suited to test implementation. A common testing strategy with it is to simulate a click and assert DOM:

```
const { getByText } = render(<App />);
fireEvent.click(app.getByText('Click me'));
await waitForElement(() => getByText('Success'));
```

The test can be additionally enforced with implementation assertions. `axios.post` is called asynchronously and a promise that it returns should be chained:

```
...
fireEvent.click(app.getByText('Click me'));
expect(axios.get).toBeCalledTimes(1);
await axios.get.mock.results[0].value;
expect(axios.post).toBeCalledTimes(1);
await waitForElement(() => getByText('Success'));
```

Comment: You're welcome. What do you mean by "no wait"? Please specify the code you're trying.

Comment: Sorry for the vague term. I meant before using waitForElement. The DOM changed which meant that the status from post response was 200 I queried the changed element successful before expect(axios.post), but post still wasn't called in my test file. In my component axios.post.mock.results[0].value had a promise which was rejected if I tried to await it there.